# Which SE site to use when posting a question suitable for multiple SE sites

Tags: discussion

I have posted a question in SU about a software freezing my computer but its freezing only when I run WP and a specific WP plugin.

The question is initially posted in SU but it belongs to WordPress site too (because of the issue with WP).

If I have a question like this in future what should I do? What's the best SE site to post the question to?

Let me explain it a little more:
I am developing a WP site locally. Visual Composer and GravityForms are the two plugins in question here.
I have put a GravityForms forms on a page and the same page's content is created using Visual Composer.
When I install new version of the theme and loads the page (with that form on it) it hangs WAMP/Apache/My PC and I have no option but to end the WAMP process via task manager.

- The same page loads fine when I use older version of the theme.

Comment: Nothing in WordPress or PHP should ever be capable of locking up a machine

Comment: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

Answer (score 2):

SU might be a good bet, though you probably need more information.

Lets break it down

If its your *browser* freezing *completely*, its an SU question

If its your *web server* freezing ... well, its an SU question.

If its your wordpress window/tab freezing... wordpress might be a better option - though I'd rather have a WP mod weigh in on that..

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the reason for the freeze. Figuring out what exactly freezes your computer is probably on topic on SU.

Once you have found the source, you can search for ways to change the code. That would belong either Stack Overflow if it is a plain JavaScript issue, or to WordPress Development if it can happen in a WordPress context only.